# arrow function returns the function text and not the result (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

The arrow function returns the function text - "(n) => 5 + n" and not the result (6). What am I doing wrong?

```
let n = 1;
let newText = (n) => 5 + n;
document.write(newText);
```

Comment: you don't invoke the function.. do like `document.write(newText(n));`

Comment: Also note that the parameter `n` hides the variable `n` within the arrow function.  If the arrow function needs access to the variable `n`, use a different name for the parameter.

Comment: You might benefit from reading a JavaScript tutorial to get a better understanding of functions: http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html .

Answer (score 5):

You're not calling the function:

```
document.write(newText(42));
```

This has nothing to do with `=>` or `let`, by the way:

```
function newText(n) { return 5 + n; }
document.write(newText);
```

has the same problem.

Comment: Why is this not working? let n = 1; document.write((n) => 123 + n);

Comment: @AlexeyTseitlin It's working fine: It writes the function to the document.

Comment: @AlexeyTseitlin Correct. If you want to call a function, you need `()`.

Answer (score 0):

Call the function

document.write(newText(5));

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the arrow function.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/manishghec/7su4g5wh/)

```
let n = 1;
let newText = (n) => 5 + n;
document.write(newText(n));
```

Comment: Why is this not working? let n = 1; document.write((n) => 123 + n);

Comment: this is not the correct behavior of arrow function.